# Angular 2 npm install error packages

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

I'm using Angular 2.Node version is `v6.9.1`. 
Npm version is: `4.0.3`.When I run `npm start` the following errors are shown:

```js
ng2-fundamentals-demo@1.0.0 start /var/www/html/ng2-fundamentals
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run server" 

app/app.module.ts(3,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events-list-resolver.service.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events/create-event.component.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events/event-details/event-details.component.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events/event-details/event-route-activator.service.ts(1,61): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events/events-list.component.ts(4,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
app/events/shared/event.service.ts(15,23): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type '({ id: number; name: string; date: string; time: string; price: number; imageUrl: string; session...'.
app/routes.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(48,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(44,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts(32,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts(44,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler_host.d.ts(20,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(342,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(344,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(346,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(348,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(350,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(352,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(38,72): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(40,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts(14,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts(22,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts(44,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts(46,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts(58,104): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(433,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(33,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(34,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(116,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(132,110): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(158,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(160,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(87,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(12,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(79,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(97,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts(22,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts(11,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts(22,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(25,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(60,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(62,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(65,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(68,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(71,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(74,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(77,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(80,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(83,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts(86,83): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(40,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(41,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(2,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

I have tried many things like that:
npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --save

and other issues but still no result.

My package.json is:

```html
{
  "name": "ng2-fundamentals-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "server": "node node_modules/ng2f-server/server.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

How to fix these errors in packages and Angular 2?

Updated: 
Now I changed package.json like that:

```js
{
  "name": "ng2-fundamentals-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "server": "node node_modules/ng2f-server/server.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.9",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I ran:
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install @angular/cli -g
npm install  @types/core-js --save-dev
npm install @angular/router -save

npm install
npm run`

and I got the same errors :

```js
> ng2-fundamentals-demo@1.0.0 start /var/www/html/ng2-fundamentals
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run server" 

app/events/shared/event.service.ts(15,23): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type '({ id: number; name: string; date: string; time: string; price: number; imageUrl: string; session...'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(44,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts(32,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler_host.d.ts(20,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(38,72): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(40,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts(14,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts(22,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts(44,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts(46,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts(58,104): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(33,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(34,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(116,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(132,110): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(158,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(160,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(12,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts(307,85): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(78,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(157,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(227,115): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(297,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts(367,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts(392,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts(414,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router/src/utils/collection.d.ts(36,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(47,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(350,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(351,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(352,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(353,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(354,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(355,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(356,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(357,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(357,97): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(358,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(359,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(360,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(361,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(362,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(362,117): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(363,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(365,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(366,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(367,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(368,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(431,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(456,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(464,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(465,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(467,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(468,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(472,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(474,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(494,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(495,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(511,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(512,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(627,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(642,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(646,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(646,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(657,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1280,34): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1284,41): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1288,48): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1292,38): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1296,36): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1300,35): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1304,37): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1308,36): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1312,37): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1316,35): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1320,41): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1324,41): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1328,41): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2059,34): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2063,41): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2067,48): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2071,38): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2075,36): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2079,35): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2083,37): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2087,36): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2091,37): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2095,35): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2099,41): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2103,41): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2107,41): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(40,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(41,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(2,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(3,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ng2-fundamentals-demo@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ng2-fundamentals-demo@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ng2-fundamentals-demo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ng2-fundamentals-demo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ng2-fundamentals-demo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/ng2-fundamentals/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: are you using **ionic**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. After couple of hours, I've realized that @types/core-js makes the problem.

Change it in package.json to version:

```
"@types/core-js": "0.9.35"
```

And of course, you have to do:

> npm install

It would be great to remove node_modules at all before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Your package.json does not have angular router. Put this in your package.json manually     `"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",` and type the command `npm install` in the same folder. Or do `npm install @angular/router --save`

The following is what a typical package.json should look like for an angular project:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Add other packages / dependencies like ionic as well to match your needs.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: I updated my question. I deleted node packages, changed package.json file,ran these commands and these errors again.

Comment: Please check your event service. The type you have specified does not have the method find on it. Its a nice time to upgrade node itself. May be you are running a very old node dist. Can you try that and also show the code where the find is applied and how?

Comment: It was working, this is a custom service. But after I updated angular-cli and node, it broke. Whatever, I'll try to change my app structure to be the same as angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

your project doesn't have angular router and @types/core-js, try to install them manually:

```
npm install @angular/router -save

npm install  @types/core-js --save-dev
```

or just use @angular/cli it will provide anything you want for an angular app :

```
npm install @angular/cli -g

ng new myapp

ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing everything with CLI worked for me I was recently having a similar issue you can try

- nvm install node
- nvm use 7.4.0(Whatever version you are using)
- nvm alias default v7.4.0
- npm install -g npm
- npm install -g @angular/cli ng new myapp
- ng serve

Comment: Yes. I've tried it and it works for a newly created project in this way. But I'm watching video tutorial in Pluralsight - https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-fundamentals&author=jim-cooper&name=angular-fundamentals-m1&clip=7&mode=live. It is used `npm start` command that is declared in systemjsconfig file and I am just trying to make it work again.

Comment: Here are the exercises files for tutorial: https://github.com/jmcooper/angular2-fundamentals-files. It is used node version 6.3 for it.

Comment: @mistery_girl you have to know that @angular/cli and wepback are the way to go, even the tuto is using systemjs. try to use @angular/cli and webpack

Comment: Well, my package.json is the same as the tutorial but now these errors appear. How should I fix that?

Comment: @mistery_girl i also am following plural sight the way how to initiate angular cli and start the project is given in old format also in there they are using system.js which is not the recommended way of angular 2 I will recommend you to just take reference from plural sight and work around with new ways since angular2 has gone through a lot of change until recently and still there are manythings changing in it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm just learning it. I'll check Angular Quick Start and documentation and after that I'll check PluralSight using the new setup.